# How to communicate between two stateProviders in river pod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

i have just recently stated working with riverpod state mangement in flutter.

i have issue related to comunicate between to state providers.

here is my sample code:

```
class SomeClass_ONE extends stateNotifer <SomeState> {
SomeClass_ONE({required this.somevalue}):super(null);
  
  final SomeCustomClass somevalue;
  
  void methodOne(SomeState newstatevalue){
      state = newstatevalue;
 }
}


final someClassOneProvider = 
StateNotifierProvider<SomeClass_ONE,SomeState>.  
((ref)=>SomeClass_ONE(somevalue: SomeCustomClass()));
```

now i have another state provider class as below

```
class SomeClass_Two extends stateNotifer <SomeStateTwo> {
SomeClass_ONE({required this.somevalue}):super(null);

 final SomeCustomClass somevalue;

 void methodtwo(SomeState newstatevalue){
   state = newstatevalue;
  }

}

final someClassTwoProvider = 
StateNotifierProvider<SomeClass_Two,SomeStateTwo> 
((ref)=>someClassTwoProvider(somevalue: SomeCustomClass()));
```

now what i want to achhive is that on methodOne execution i have to listen that state cahnge and have to trigger  methodTow and have to upate secondproviders state as well.

so how can i achive this without using Ref in class cunstroctors?

i have tried with ref.listner to trigger  and have passed Ref in both class constructors. but as per some condition i can't use Ref directly in constructors as per some guideline followed by seniors.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Ref ref` object to the `methodtwo` method and then call the necessary methods from other `StateNotifierProvider`. In any case, to refer to other methods of other classes, you need to have a `Ref` object.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `watch` provided by `StateNotifierProvider`

Try this code:

```
class SomeClass_ONE extends stateNotifer <SomeState> {
  SomeClass_ONE({required this.somevalue}):super(null);
  
  final SomeCustomClass somevalue;
  
  void methodOne(SomeState newstatevalue){
    state = newstatevalue;
    // Listen to the changes in the state of the first provider and call the methodtwo of the second provider
    someClassTwoProvider.watch((_) => _.methodtwo(newstatevalue));
  }
}
```

Comment: hello  Unkonwn Developer

i have not able to call  watch method to someClassTwoProvider. as it has no any method in someClassTwoProvider. 

as of my knowledge of riverpod watch method only can work on Ref.